# Неоднозначное поведение protoc

Tags: google-protobuf

Почему компиляция протоком происходит кооректно в следующем случае:

```
protoc --proto_path=. --proto_path=./third_party --go_out=. api/proto/v2/common.proto
```

Если же изменить `proto_path`, то всё крашится:

```
protoc --proto_path=api/proto/v2/ --proto_path=./third_party --go_out=. common.proto
```

Это эквивалентные вещи? Исходя из результатов, оказывается, это не так

Comment: а если так? `protoc --proto_path=./api/proto/v2/ --proto_path=./third_party --go_out=. common.proto`

Comment: Не работает. Скорее всего вопрос был в версии. Я поставил с помощью `apt-get`. Если собрать из исходников, то всё заводится